# Powershell variable won't expand in Get-Process command

Tags: powershell, csv, variables

Why would the $servername variable expand correctly in `$servername` below, but not in the following `Get-Process -ComputerName $servername` line?

1) If I manually set`$servername="example-server"` to an example server in that list (copy/paste) within the loop, it works.
2) If I insert the line `$servername | Measure-Object -Character` within the loop to try to test if the variable contents are correct (hidden space or something), I don't get any output. However, if I manually assign `$servername` and run, it displays the correct number of characters in the string.

```
$servers = Import-CSV C:\temp\AllServers.csv
foreach ($servername in $servers)
    {
    $servername
    Get-Process -ComputerName $servername | Where-Object {$_.Handles -gt 1000} | Sort-Object Handles -Descending
    }
```

Is there some processing or formatting needed with csv-assigned arrays that I'm missing?

The contents of `AllServers.csv` is one column, first row being the column heading `servers`.

Comment: `Get-Process -ComputerName $servername.servers`

Comment: @PetSerAl Ah, missed that, my apologies.

Comment: As @PetSerAl indicates the problem is that your $servername variable is not a string but rather a csv row object. You need to use the correct field in your call. Also -ComputerName can take an array of strings directly.

Comment: That resolved, thank you both. No exotic badges earned for this one, I imagine, but it sure improved my Monday.

Answer (score 0):

The comments by @PetSerAl and @Etan Reisner above were correct... I needed to call the exact field object in the row: `$servername.server` in this case worked.

```
$servers = Import-CSV C:\temp\AllServers.csv
foreach ($servername in $servers)
    {
    $servername.server
    Get-Process -ComputerName $servername.server | Where-Object {$_.Handles -gt 1000} | Sort-Object Handles -Descending
    }
```